# Awk separate column output

Tags: bash, awk

What I wanted to do is to create a Table (maximum=4 rows) from a one-column file using awk. 
I have a file:

```
1 a,b
2 r,i
3 w
4 r,t
5 o,s
6 y
```

The desire output:

```
1 a,b   5 o,s
2 r,i   6 y
3 w
4 r,t
```

So far, I just separating the rows into different files and "paste" them into one. I would appreciate of any of more sophisticated method.

Comment: How can I know which lines of the column to join?

Comment: `pr -bt2` with some option to set the page length which I don't remember offhand. Voting to close as not a programming question.

Comment: @tripleee, seems like `pr` with `-l4` for page length 4, "balances" lines between columns. Not sure if it can be told to first fill column 1 (up to max page length), then column 2, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    numRows = 4
    OFS = "\t"
}
{
    rowNr = (NR - 1 ) % numRows + 1
    if ( rowNr == 1 ) {
        numCols++
    }
    val[rowNr,numCols] = $0
}
END {
    for (rowNr=1; rowNr<=numRows; rowNr++) {
        for (colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++) {
            printf "%s%s", val[rowNr,colNr], (colNr<numCols ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
1 a,b   5 o,s
2 r,i   6 y
3 w
4 r,t
```

Answer (score 3):

Combination of `awk` to join lines and `column` to pretty-print them:

```
awk -v max=4 '
    { i = (NR-1) % max + 1; line[i] = line[i] "\t" $0 }
    END { for(i=1; i<=max && i<=length(line); i++) print line[i] }' file | column -t -s $'\t'
```

Output:

```
1 a,b  5 o,s
2 r,i  6 y
3 w
4 r,t
```

Answer (score 1):

Another:

```
$ awk ' {
    i=(NR%4)                         # using modulo indexed array 
    a[i]=a[i] (a[i]==""?"":"  ") $0  # append to it
}
END {                                # in the END 
    for(i=1;i<=4;i++)                # loop all indexes in order
        print a[i%4]                 # dont forget the modulo
}' file
1 a,b  5 o,s
2 r,i  6 y
3 w
4 r,t
```

Naturally it will be ugly if there are missing columns.

Comment: It seems to have turned out pretty much like @randomir's (^), basically appending to array. Slight differencies in implementation so I'll leave it here anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another awk approach:-

```
awk '
        {
                A[++c] = $0
        }
        END {
                m = sprintf ( "%.0f", ( c / 4 ) )
                for ( i = 1; i <= 4; i++ )
                {
                        printf "%s\t", A[i]
                        for ( j = 1; j <= m; j++ )
                                printf "%s\t", A[i+(j*4)]
                        printf "\n"
                }
        }
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

you can combine split and paste

```
split -l 4 file part- && paste part-*
```

- `-l <number>` means to split file to smaller files of `<number>` lines each.
- `part-` is a prefix of our choice to be used for the new files. Note that they will be in alphabetical order, e.g. `part-aa`, `part-ab` etc. So `paste` will paste them as expected.